# What kind of siding is this?

Tags: exterior, siding

I need help identifying the siding in the picture. I like the style a lot. Fwiw this house is in the middle Atlantic on an area that has a decent bit of humidity and moderate winters.

Overview:
[image]

Detail:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you knock on the door of one of the houses that look like this and simply ask. "Hey, sir/ma'am, I _really_ like the look of the outside of your house! What kind of material is that?" _Most_ people will appreciate the compliment and happily answer. Probably also give you references to whoever did the work (if they know) and let you get some closeup pics, too, for your future reference.

Comment: I tried that, no one was home. I left a note and my contact information and haven’t gotten a response.

Comment: You may try knocking on several doors, since you've indicated that there is more than one house in your area that's sided like this. I'm sure _someone_ would be happy to talk to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your photo leaves a lot to be desired but this looks like multi-colored hexagonal SHINGLES instead of actual siding.

UPDATE: Your new photo is very helpful.  Clearly those are colored hexagonal asphalt shingles applied as siding.

Comment: Is there a reason why someone would put shingles on the sides on the sides of their house, besides the aesthetic? There are multiple houses in my city that have the same shingles on the sides, though vinyl and brick are the most common siding materials.

Comment: They are probably custom pre-stained **cedar**.

Comment: You'd have to ask the person who applied this why they used shingles.  Perhaps it's what they had available.  A better photo, like a close-up, might shed more light on this.  But the surface appears to be granular from what I see in the photo.

Comment: While I agree, in general (and up voted), it doesn't appear that there's any overlap...

Comment: Color me wrong... based on the new pic, those definitely do overlap! They also look like asphalt shingles, not colored/stained/painted cedar. Those look like the decorative type of shingle I've seen on barn roofs here in the Midwest where they use them to spell out the owner's name or the building's year of construction on the roof.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that not any old asphalt shingle will work like this. They aren't designed to carry their own weight on nails. You'd need special wall shingles. FYI, cedar planks used on walls are also called shingles.